# PassportJS req.user not deserializing

Tags: sails.js, passport.js

I have tried to serialised and deserialised the user successfully within SailsJS's policy. An example would be this:

`userAuth`

```
var passport = require('passport');

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {

  // Check for authorization headers
  if(req.get('authorization')){
    passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }, function(err, user, info) {
      if ((err) || (!user)) {
        return res.json(
          {'status':0,
            'message':'incorrect username or password'}
        );
      }
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        next();
      });
    })(req, res);
  }else{
    // If authentication via session, make sure that authorization headers are off
    var is_auth = req.isAuthenticated();
    if (is_auth) {
      // Ensure that session remembers that user is logged in,
      // so that views can reference to them
      req.session.isAuthenticated = true;
      if (req.user.doctor){
        req.session.isDoctor = true;
      }else{
        req.session.isDoctor = false;
      }
      return next();
    }else{  // User is not allowed
      req.session.isAuthenticated = false;
      res.status(401);
      res.view("user/login");
    }
  }

};
```

As you can see, the deserialising of req.user when `console.log` gives me more than just the deserialised object. However, it appears that my usercontroller:login doesn't deserialise req.user when I call it. More information can be seen below:

`login`

```
process: function(req, res){
    passport.authenticate( ['local'] , function(err, user, info) {
      if ((err) || (!user)) {
        req.session.flash = {
          message : "incorrect username or password"
        }
        return res.redirect('/user/login');
      }
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        req.session.user = user;
        console.log(req.user);
        if(req.user.doctor){
          return res.redirect('/assessment/index');
        }else{
          return res.redirect('/user/show/'+req.session.user.id);
        }

      });
    })(req, res);
  },
```

`console.log`

```
{ username: 'username',
  createdAt: Mon Feb 09 2015 19:59:04 GMT+0800 (SGT),
  id: '54d8a108322359745faf0c5b' }
```

Am I misinterpreting something? I need to retrieve the deserialised object from req.user and it seems that the only option for me now is to do a manual User.find(id..). Any help is appreciated! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that within `passport.authenticate`, there is a object that is returned within it's callback. Therefore, req.user will now be the returned user that was created by `passport.use(new LocalStrategy(..)`'s callback.

To fixed that, we have to add the attributes we want for req.user. Now it looks something like this:

```
var returnUser = {
            username: user.username,
            doctor: user.doctor,
            createdAt: user.createdAt,
            id: user.id
          };
          return done(null, returnUser, {
            message: 'Logged In Successfully'
          });
```